# Website unavailable when loaded with WebView

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, webview

I am trying to load a url with webview that loads perfectly fine on mobile using chrome, but the website says "Website temporarily unavailable". I tried changing the user agent to no avail. I can't figure out for the life of me why this is happening. The url in question is https://www.manototv.com/news

[A screenshot of loading with webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83wm4.jpg)

[A screenshot of loading with chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VogPI.jpg)

Relevant portion of the code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWeb());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome());
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl(path)
    }

    class MyWeb extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            setTitle(view.getTitle());            
            mWebView.loadUrl(SCRIPT_FULLSCREEN);
            mWebView.loadUrl(SCRIPT_CLICK);
            mWebView.loadUrl(SCRIPT_PLAY);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {
        private View mCustomView;
        private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
        private int mOriginalOrientation;
        private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

        @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            ((FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
            this.mCustomView = null;
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
            setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
            this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback) {
            if (this.mCustomView != null) {
                onHideCustomView();
                return;
            }
            this.mCustomView = paramView;
            this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
            this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
            this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
            ((FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add code that you have tried

Comment: @NagvadiyaVishal Added the relevant portion of the code.

Comment: can anyone help with this?